Why does my rotor not fit my mechanical disc brakes suddenly
I have a 2021 GT Aggressor with mechanical disc brakes. I bought this brand new from Dicks Sporting Goods so I know it's all original parts. I know that my rear rotor is bent and I purchased the rotor truing tool from parktool. When trying to diagnose reason for extreme brake rub, I did attempt to realign caliper to see if that was the issue. I believe I positioned it correctly. So I think it is a bent rotor however now i cant even get the wheel back on the bike because the rotor won't fit in between the brake pads on the caliper.  I completely loosened the caliper and unscrewed the brake pads all the way out but still it won't fit! Why is that? Did I do something wrong? Do I need to push my pads back into a certain position?

What model are your brakes? The issue is almost certainly with the calipers. What happens if you take them off completely, install the wheel, then fit them (might not be possible with all mounting styles)?

Look inside the caliper. The brake pads need to be at least 2mm apart for the brake disk to fit. If that is not the case, that is your problem. If you have 2mm+ of space between the pads, the disk will fit if oriented correctly. Maybe you accidentally screwed your static pad in instead of out?
